# Liquibase-hibernate plugin with orm.xml configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

Im thinking about starting a java project with the idea of separate the domain classes from everything related to the persistence layer. Then, I want to use hibernate or jpa with the xml mappings configuration (in a orm.xml file) and with liquibase to control the database changes.

It would be great to use liquibase-hibernate plugin to generate the db changesets but im not sure if it is possible.

Can someone tell me if it is possible and if it is a good idea?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

1. Yes, it is possible with [liquibase-hibernate](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate), check out the `project description` and `wiki`.
2. But I don't think it's a good idea, there might be some issues with it, especially if your `database schema` will be complex. I'd write `liquibase changeSets` myself and use `hibernate` just for schema validation, using this property: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`.

But your question is too generic to give a direct answer.